# Juntar valores com vírgula caso a chave seja iguais

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, formulário

Como formatar uma array assim...

```
[
{name: "city", value: "sao-paulo-sp"},
{name: "types-properties", value: "apartamento"},
{name: "types-properties", value: "casa"}
]
```

para chegar neste resultado.

```
[
{name: "city", value: "sao-paulo-sp"},
{name: "types-properties", value: "apartamento,casa"}
]
```

Estes dados são puxados de um formulário e formatados com [.serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

De início, pensei em fazer um `.map()`, comparar as chave e se existisse na array que eu dei um `.push()`, juntaria os valores com vírgula.

Testei desta forma [aqui](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/), mas na URL fica vazia ou null, então não lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há várias maneiras de fazer isso... se o `name` é a chave única podes fazer um objeto e concatenar os `value` no valor da chave `name`.

Algo assim:

```js
const array = [{
    name: "city",
    value: "sao-paulo-sp"
  },
  {
    name: "types-properties",
    value: "apartamento"
  },
  {
    name: "types-properties",
    value: "casa"
  }
];

const obj = array.reduce((obj, entry) => {

  if (!obj[entry.name]) obj[entry.name] = [];
  obj[entry.name].push(entry.value);
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

// dá 
//  {
//    "city":["sao-paulo-sp"],
//    "types-properties":["apartamento","casa"]
//  }
```

É bem possível que seja isso que precises.
Se quiseres mesmo o formato que referes podes dar mais um passo, agora que já tens tudo organizado e fazer:

```
const arrayOrganizada = Object.keys(obj).map(name => {
  return {
    name: name,
    value: obj[name].join(',')
  }
});
```

Tudo junto seria assim:

```js
const array = [{
    name: "city",
    value: "sao-paulo-sp"
  },
  {
    name: "types-properties",
    value: "apartamento"
  },
  {
    name: "types-properties",
    value: "casa"
  }
];

const obj = array.reduce((obj, entry) => {

  if (!obj[entry.name]) obj[entry.name] = [];
  obj[entry.name].push(entry.value);
  return obj;
}, {});

const arrayOrganizada = Object.keys(obj).map(name => {
  return {
    name: name,
    value: obj[name].join(',')
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOrganizada));

// dá
//  [
//    {"name":"city","value":"sao-paulo-sp"},
//    {"name":"types-properties","value":"apartamento,casa"}
//  ]
```